# Alfresco rules vs Alfresco JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am developing a web project that uses Alfresco as CMS, and I use Alfresco rules to perform some simple tasks such as move or copy files and folders.

I have just discovered the Alfresco Javascript API, which seems a very interesting choice to perform these kind of tasks.

Which tool is better in terms of performance?

Comment: what did you mean by which tool,do you mean rule vs javascript api?

Comment: Yes Krutik, that's what I mean, sorry for my bad english

Comment: I am using both for a CMS project. Specifically, I am using WCMQS and associated rules for approval of content. Then, a series of Script act on the approved folder for converting, transforming, and replicating (via FTR) the approved web site to static web site, which is then served by Apache.

Comment: Well ,I dont think there will be any performance change in alfresco javascript vs rules which you have created.On the back end there will be same things.Still it depends on the rule which you have created and the code which you have written in javascript.